# When should I use punctuation with bullets?

Tags: formatting, punctuation, business-writing

When writing bulleted items, what are the rules for placing periods?
Presumably bulleted items that aren't sentences wouldn't require punctuation:

- Orange
- Apple
- Banana

But how about sentence bullets?

- I am happy
- She was happy
- He is happy still

Should that be:

- I am happy.
- She was happy.
- He is happy still?

And how do I distinguish between cases? What happens if there are multiple sentences per bullet?

**Update:**
This is actually going to be published from a corporate website, so the house rules are less clearly defined in that case, but I think that is a great point regardless.

Comment: Is this more of an English SE question than a Writers SE question?

Comment: People who speak other languages may also have this doubt (my case) :) - unless it has some specific norm or rule concerning English

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to use periods with full-sentence bullets, but it depends on the house style of wherever you're submitting your writing. My only caveat is that if you have a list where some items are full sentences and some are not, you have to be consistent: either they all get periods (even the phrases or single words) or they all don't (even the full sentences).

If there are multiple sentences per bullet, I would end the final one with a period (or whatever the appropriate punctuation is), and if it's house style not to, I would ask the person to whom I'm submitting it how s/he wants you to handle that instance.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will be going with a period after each sentence. I think it makes the most sense at this point.

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways I've seen this done.

For single word items, I suggest either use no punctuation, or use semi-colons, with a period for the last item. For example:

- Apples;
- Pears;
- Oranges.

You could use the same type of structure for sentences as well:

- I am happy;
- She was happy;
- He is happy still.

Alternatively, use full punctuation for single sentences.

Likewise, if each bullet is more than just one sentence, then I would follow full punctuation rules, since it's quite clear that I'm using bullet points for a very complicated list of items.

Having said that, however, as Lauren says, it's best to ask for the house rules first. And the number one rule is: be consistent in whatever you choose.

**Edit:** I found this article which you may find helpful: http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/formatting-vertical-lists.aspx

Most of the article is based on a book called the "Chicago Manual of Style". I won't duplicate what is written there, but it is extremely comprehensive. Also, it's worth pointing out that, while the writer doesn't like the usage of semi-colons, in a footnote she says, 'commas are optional in some lists and allows the conjunction *and* after the penultimate list item if you are using semicolons at the end of each list item and closing the last item with terminal punctuation'.

Comment: +1 for the point about it being more important to be consistent. I think I will go with periods for all my sentence bullets. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Cool. Btw, edited my answer to give you a link to a rather comprehensive exploration on the topic. Glad I could help.

Comment: The virtue of this style is that it is a possible approach to punctuating the list inline inside a single sentence (e.g., "For example: (a) Apples; (b) Oranges; (c) Pears.")  But note that this is a minority approach.  *Chicago* is the most important scholarly style guide.